# On running more than 70-80 no.of test lines in a single test case then it shows “socket hang up error” or "ESOCKETTIMEDOUT"

Tags: android, appium, katalon-studio

On running more than 70-80 no.of test lines in a test case then it shows “socket hang up error” or "ESOCKETTIMEDOUT". Suddenly the test stops performing the test codes and after lets say 15-20 mins it gives the error.

If I make 2 individual test cases with 60 lines each then both of them gets completed successfully without giving any error but if i merge both of the test cases and run a single test case with 120 lines then it usually stops after 70-80th line. Again if I comment out 10 lines at the top then the test case runs till 80-90th line and then stops again.

I can’t find out what the actual issue is. It seems like an appium issue to me.
I've tried updating appium and katalon studio but still the issue comes, tested in different android devices also.

```
> com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Cannot swipe on
> device. (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
> unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original
> error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT Build info: version: '3.141.59',
> revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host:
> 'Subhajits-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '192.168.29.5', os.name: 'Mac OS
> X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version:
> '1.8.0_181' Driver info:
> com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver Capabilities
> {app: /Users/iamsubho2/Downloads/..., appPackage:
> com.lc_seenit.elsie_dev, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName:
> uiautomator2, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app:
> /Users/iamsubho2/Downloads/..., autoGrantPermissions: true,
> automationName: uiautomator2, deviceName: OnePlus ONEPLUS A5000
> (Andr..., fullReset: false, newCommandTimeout: 1800, noReset: true,
> platform: ANDROID, platformName: android, platformVersion: 9, udid:
> 3d999502}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: OnePlus,
> deviceModel: ONEPLUS A5000, deviceName: 3d999502, deviceScreenDensity:
> 380, deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, deviceUDID: 3d999502, fullReset:
> false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false,
> networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 1800, noReset:
> true, pixelRatio: 2.375, platform: ANDROID, platformName: Android,
> platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 57, takesScreenshot: true, udid:
> 3d999502, viewportRect: {height: 1863, left: 0, top: 57, width: 1080},
> warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false} Session ID:
> dc1a58af-f530-45b0-afad-6587fb500e00  at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.execute(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions.performTouchAction(PerformsTouchActions.java:41)
>   at io.appium.java_client.TouchAction.perform(TouchAction.java:187)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.helper.MobileCommonHelper.swipe(MobileCommonHelper.java:37)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword$_swipe_closure1.doCall(SwipeKeyword.groovy:76)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword$_swipe_closure1.call(SwipeKeyword.groovy)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileKeywordMain.runKeyword(MobileKeywordMain.groovy:21)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword.swipe(SwipeKeyword.groovy:71)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword.execute(SwipeKeyword.groovy:66)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords.swipe(MobileBuiltInKeywords.groovy:153)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords$swipe$1.call(Unknown
> Source)   at PreBuild1.run(PreBuild1:194)     at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)     at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:342)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:333)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:304)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:238)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
>   at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
> Source)   at
> TempTestCase1560160422043.run(TempTestCase1560160422043.groovy:21) )
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy:48)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileKeywordMain.stepFailed(MobileKeywordMain.groovy:40)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileKeywordMain.runKeyword(MobileKeywordMain.groovy:23)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword.swipe(SwipeKeyword.groovy:71)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword.execute(SwipeKeyword.groovy:66)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords.swipe(MobileBuiltInKeywords.groovy:153)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords$swipe$1.call(Unknown
> Source)   at PreBuild1.run(PreBuild1:194)     at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)     at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:342)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:333)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:304)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:238)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
>   at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
> Source)   at
> TempTestCase1560160422043.run(TempTestCase1560160422043.groovy:21)
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown
> server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
> error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error:
> Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
> 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host:
> 'Subhajits-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '192.168.29.5', os.name: 'Mac OS
> X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version:
> '1.8.0_181' Driver info:
> com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver Capabilities
> {app: /Users/iamsubho2/Downloads/..., appPackage:
> com.lc_seenit.elsie_dev, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName:
> uiautomator2, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app:
> /Users/iamsubho2/Downloads/..., autoGrantPermissions: true,
> automationName: uiautomator2, deviceName: OnePlus ONEPLUS A5000
> (Andr..., fullReset: false, newCommandTimeout: 1800, noReset: true,
> platform: ANDROID, platformName: android, platformVersion: 9, udid:
> 3d999502}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: OnePlus,
> deviceModel: ONEPLUS A5000, deviceName: 3d999502, deviceScreenDensity:
> 380, deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, deviceUDID: 3d999502, fullReset:
> false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false,
> networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 1800, noReset:
> true, pixelRatio: 2.375, platform: ANDROID, platformName: Android,
> platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 57, takesScreenshot: true, udid:
> 3d999502, viewportRect: {height: 1863, left: 0, top: 57, width: 1080},
> warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false} Session ID:
> dc1a58af-f530-45b0-afad-6587fb500e00  at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.execute(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions.performTouchAction(PerformsTouchActions.java:41)
>   at io.appium.java_client.TouchAction.perform(TouchAction.java:187)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.helper.MobileCommonHelper.swipe(MobileCommonHelper.java:37)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword$_swipe_closure1.doCall(SwipeKeyword.groovy:76)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.builtin.SwipeKeyword$_swipe_closure1.call(SwipeKeyword.groovy)
>   at
> com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileKeywordMain.runKeyword(MobileKeywordMain.groovy:21)
>   ... 16 more
```

The expected result will be that all the test cases should complete without showing that error.

Comment: Please post the code too.

Comment: Search for `MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT` it might be your problem.

Comment: @BillHileman Dont think this would help as this is only for timeout between commands I'm assuming ?

Comment: please provide the appium server logs

Comment: At first glance looks like a version control problem. Update every-thing to latest versions.

Comment: > Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown
> server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
> error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error:
> Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
> 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host:
> 'Subhajits-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '192.168.29.5', os.name: 'Mac OS
> X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version:
> '1.8.0_181' Driver info: ***Probable Library problem***

Comment: You should exit after ending a use case file
like
cls.driver.quit()
or
self.driver.quit()

Answer (score 1):

to reinstall the Appium packages appears to be the most likely approach:

```
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
adb uninstall io.appium.unlock
adb uninstall io.appium.settings
```

found on [GitHub](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11538).